# Function to decrypt file in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, structure

I have a file with a large number of 'prospects', so each line has an encrypted last name, an encrypted first name, a 12 digit id code, and then 4 ratings (3 ints, 1 float). Encryption is shifting every character of the names by the value of the last number in the file (found to be 310).

Attempted to create a function to decrypt 1 character, then another function to decrypt a string (name) using this function, but am getting errors and segmentation faults, please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MSTRLEN 20
#define MAX_SIZE 1000

/* structure prototype */
typedef struct {
    char lastname[MSTRLEN];
    char firstname[MSTRLEN];
    char secretcode[13];
    int rank1;
    int rank2;
    float rank3;
    int rank4;
} prospect_t;

int main (void)
{

    FILE *ifile;
    prospect_t *prospects;
    char last[MSTRLEN],first[MSTRLEN],code[13],last_name,first_name;
    int r1,r2,r4,num_prospects,shift,i,j;
    float r3;

    char unencrypt_letter(char *letter, int shift);
    char unencrypt_name(char name[MSTRLEN], int shift);


    /*finding how many prospects and last integer*/
    ifile = fopen("prospects.txt","r");
    num_prospects = 0;

    if (ifile == NULL){ 
        printf("File not found!\n");
        return (-1);
    }
    while (fscanf(ifile,"%s %s %s %d %d %f %d",last,first,code,&r1,&r2,&r3,&r4)!=EOF){
        num_prospects++;
    }
    shift = r4%26;
    fclose(ifile);
    /*--------------------------------------*/

    /* dynamic memory allocation */
    prospects = (prospect_t*)malloc(num_prospects*sizeof(prospect_t));

    ifile = fopen("prospects.txt","r");

    if (ifile == NULL){ 
        printf("File not found!\n");
        return (-1);
    }

    for(i=0;i<num_prospects;i++){
        fscanf(ifile,"%s %s %s %d %d %f %d", prospects[i].lastname,prospects[i].firstname,prospects[i].secretcode,&prospects[i].rank1,&prospects[i].rank2,&prospects[i].rank3,&prospects[i].rank4); 
    }
    /* to be used once get working
    for(j=0;j<num_prospects;j++){
        prospects[j].lastname = unencrypt_name(prospects[j].lastname,shift);
        prospects[j].firstname = unencrypt_name(prospects[j].firstname,shift);
    }
    */
    /* to be taken out once working */
    last_name = unencrypt_name(prospects[0].lastname,shift);
    first_name = unencrypt_name(prospects[0].firstname,shift);

    printf("%s %s\n",last_name,first_name);



    fclose(ifile);      

    free(prospects);
    return(0);
}

/* function to unencrypt one letter */
char unencrypt_letter(char *letter, int shift)
{
char *new_letter;

if ((*letter - shift) < 'a')
    *new_letter = (char)((*letter - shift) + 26);
else
    *new_letter = (char)(*letter - shift);

return(*new_letter);
}
/* function to unencrypt a name */
char unencrypt_name(char name[MSTRLEN],int shift)
{
char new_name[MSTRLEN];
int k;

k = 0;

while (name[k] != '\0'){
    new_name[k] = unencrypt_letter(name[k],shift);
    k++;
}
return(*new_name);
}
```

From terminal, I am getting the following:

```
la2.c: In function ‘main’:
la2.c:68:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
la2.c:68:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
la2.c: In function ‘unencrypt_name’:
la2.c:99:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘unencrypt_letter’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
la2.c:79:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
```

** Link phase
gcc -o la2 la2.o

Compile and link completed successfully
Your binary can be run by typing:
    la2
engs20-1:~/engs20/workspace$ la2
Segmentation fault

Answer (score 1):

Read the warnings again, they are quite clear:

```
la2.c:68:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

It tells you that the second argument to the `printf` call on line 68 is expected to be a string (`char *`) but you pass an integer (actually a single `char`, but the compiler casts it to `int`) as that argument instead.

Later when you run the program `printf` uses that integer as a pointer to a string, and as that integer is not a proper integer the program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 2nd `fscanf` is line 68

```
fscanf(ifile,"%s %s %s %d %d %f %d", prospects[i].lastname,prospects[i].firstname,prospects[i].secretcode,&prospects[i].rank1,&prospects[i].rank2,&prospects[i].rank3,&prospects[i].rank4);
```

I'd stick some `()` in to make sure you are getting the address of what you think.

```
&(prospects[i].lastname), ...
```

You don't pre declare `char unencrypt_letter(char *letter, int shift)` before you call it, so the compiler assumes it returns an int.

Add a predeclaration of it before `main()`.